# Creating a scm browser for an RCP application

Tags: plugins, rcp, maven-scm

I have an RCP app that saves its project as an xml file and currently the user just selections a directory to save that file and then uses the open file dialog to open the project. We are thinking about enhancing it to allow users to check in/out from a source code manager. This will make it easier for users to share their projects with each others with all the benefits of a scm. I need something similar to Subclipses, but i was thinking of using the maven svn plugin so that it is more flexible which on which scm is used. It would probably better to keep it simple because most users won't have a clue what a scm is. An ideal would be just having a Checkout menu option which opens a dialog similar to the Open File dialog. I was wondering if anyone had an example of how to use the maven scm. What calls to make to set the scm location and to get the file? Or if there is a better way of going about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could look at how the [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/) or [Continuum](http://continuum.apache.org/) use it.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with [Maven-SCM](http://maven.apache.org/scm/guide/usage.html).